# What is the Cthaeh in Wise Man's Fear?

Tags: patrick-rothfuss, the-kingkiller-chronicle

What is the Cthaeh in Wise Man's Fear?

> Bast has an almost absurd fear of it.  From how they described it, it sounds like by simply talking to the tree, it would make you notorious in history, being single-handedly responsible for bringing about plagues and starting wars.

Also,

> You can ask it anything and it must tell the truth, and by the things it tells you, it will make you be the worst kind of person you can be?  I'm not sure I completely understand the idea.

And what is it that Kvothe does that is so horrible?  Didn't they sort of imply that he was the cause for the war?

Is this Cthaeh supposed to be the prophetical "Broken Tree" that he mentioned in his first book?

Comment: "Broken Tree" refers to Kvothe himself.

Comment: There's got to be some relationship there.  It can't be a coincidence that he runs into a terribly evil tree and is named "Broken Tree".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The insidious thing about the Cthaeh's influence is that you cannot escape it.  If you know it's danger, and think "I have to kill myself instantly to protect the world" --well of course, the Cthaeh knew what your reaction would be, so if you kill yourself, **that** is what will cause the damage in the end.  And if you realize that, then you must realize that the Cthaeh knew you would.  Thus no matter what you do, it is going to be the worst possible thing--at least so far as it is influenced by the Cthaeh's words.

This creature is one of the greatest and most chilling 'monster' creations in literature.  The more you consider it, the better it is.

One question I have is: What effect does its bite have?  That was the instant worry of Felurian--that he was bitten.  What an excellent touch by Rothfuss!  It's unseen so the imagination of the reader supplies the most horrifying interpretation--Lovecraft-style.  And the effect of its bite is unspoken but suggested to be really, really bad and scary, so the reader's imagination is once again fueled to provide the most frightening and disturbing possibilities.    Love it.

Comment: Maybe being bitten is what turns a person into one of the Chandrian.  :)

Comment: Bast's fear assumes that the Cthaeh's position of privileged foresight grants it *leverage* to dramatically affect the course of the future for the malevolent. For example, the range of possibilities of evil resulting from Kvothe's possible futures may range from 'saves the world' to 'the price of butter increases 1.2% faster year over year for about the next decade and a half'. Just seeing all possible futures does not mean that a few minutes of interaction permits one to program the universe to one's will.

Answer (score 13):

The Cthaeh is a Fae creature described as an omniscient being having the ability to see all possible timelines.  It is also said to be perfectly malicious/malevolent, in that when given an opportunity to do so it will always choose the timeline that causes the greatest amount of misery/suffering/despair for the greatest number of people.

Thus the Cthaeh is a perfect manipulator.  It does not do anything directly, but if there is something that it can say to a person to cause them to bring ruin and destruction to themselves and others then that is what it will do without fail.  So it won't bring the plague itself, but it may convince a plague-infested person that they need to return to their home city and confront their spouse over the affair that they have been secretly having for the past year, resulting in a bloody confrontation that ultimately brings the plague into the city.

However this doesn't mean that the Cthaeh can turn anyone into an unstoppable instrument of destruction.  For instance, if we imagine a person dying of poison who stumbles upon the Cthaeh with only minutes or hours left to live, there is very little malevolent purpose that it might bend them towards.  However the Cthaeh works in subtle ways, using the people it manipulates to manipulate other, more influential people perhaps years or decades down the line.  This can be exceedingly dangerous, particularly when it is given the opportunity to manipulate a young, healthy, powerful, and short-tempered subject like Kvothe.

> The thing to take away from this is that everything that Kvothe does after his conversation with the Cthaeh is essentially tainted by its influence.  We don't know exactly what it is that he does yet, but it's probable that he kills a king (possibly Denna's yet unnamed patron) thereby starting a war.  It's also possible that he may be directly or indirectly responsible for the demons (the scrael, the demon that possessed the soldier and killed Shep) that have been appearing in the mortal plane.  Plus it appears that whatever happens he ultimately ends up losing Denna, his ability to make music, his ability to perform sympathy, and perhaps also his Ademic combat ability and his skill at naming.  And the Chandrian remain at large.  Given this, it seems that the Cthaeh is quite dangerous indeed.  It set the world in turmoil, and robbed Kvothe of everything he held dear.

Comment: So there's no hope for a happy ending?  :)

Comment: Well, we are seeing the "ending" since the start: Kvothe hides in a tavern, fakes its own death, and loses all his powers.

Comment: There is nothing about his situation that implies he has lost his powers.

Comment: @NappingRabbit - Except for one instance where he explicitly tries to use them and fails, and gets beaten to a pulp as a result.  And one where he implicitly doesn't use any powers while hunting scrael, again sustaining injury as a result.  He's either lost his powers, or become a masochist.

Comment: it may seem silly but I actually considered it the latter.  I am on my second pass through the pair now, but I thought he had some yet to be told 'moral or ethical or whatever' compunction to not use them.

Comment: @aroth Kvothe *wanted* to get beaten to a pulp in the tavern: if he busted out the fancy fighting and magic it would have been equivalent to a big neon arrow in the sky point at him and spelling out the words "Kvothe is here!" Getting beat up perpetuates the role of Kote he has built for  himself. Kvothe would not have got his ass kicked, but *Kote* would have. So I do not think we have evidence that he somehow lost his abilities.

Comment: I think telling his story to Chronicler _is_ the "big neon arrow in the sky".  The word is _out_, or at least, firmly on its way out.  Nothing from that passage in the book gave me any impression that Kvothe is deliberately trying to keep up the Kote fiction anymore.  Besides, there weren't any witnesses around when he went out to fight the scrael.  Why would he sustain such injuries against them if he still has full access to his abilities?

Comment: I feel like Kvothe might have _changed_ his own name.  Remember when Kvothe is talking to Elodin about Denna's names?  Elodin seems very worried that it's Fela who was using a new name.  Because names are so important in the world, it seems reasonable to think as long as Kvothe is considering himself to be "Kote", he doesn't have the powers and skills that he had as Kvothe.  I think this is what Bast has been trying to undo.

Answer (score 9):

The thing is, I get the feeling that while the Cthaeh is horribly powerful in its manipulations, it is not as all knowing as Bast made it out to be.

Think about it. If it were truly omniscient and malevolent, why would it have performed any action that would have led the Fae to blockade its tree? In its very essence, that prevents it from manipulating people to accomplish the greatest malice. If it were all knowing and wanted to accomplish the greatest harm, it would act more subtly so as to never alert those around it to its true nature, thus freeing it to speak to more people and accomplish more harm. And if you know EVERYTHING that can possibly happen, it wouldn't be hard to cause extreme amounts of harm without letting people know you caused it.

So, the way I see it, there are four major possibilities:

1. The Cthaeh can see the future, but is not all knowing--there is a limit to how well he can know what to do and how to manipulate.
2. The Cthaeh is all knowing, but the nature of Rothfuss's universe is more fluid and quantum--nothing is set in stone. The Cthaeh can merely influence events to be more likely to result in the greatest harm, but not assure that it happens.
3. The Cthaeh is all knowing and can manipulate to assure the most harm--but it nature was known from the very beginning, perhaps before it was born, and so the Fae set out to limit it.
4. The Cthaeh is not malevolent, or at least not totally.

There are two other possibilities that spring to mind--the first, the Cthaeh is all knowing and can assure the future it manipulates towards, but cannot control its impulses, and tries to do the most harm as fast as possible, which allowed its nature to be known. This doesn't seem likely as its nature seems to be patient--after all, if instant gratification was its thing, wouldn't it simply enrage Kvothe to do violence to the nearest possible person?

The second--The Cthaeh is all knowing, it can assure the future it selects, and it only let its nature be known...because being trapped is part of its overarching plan that in the end causes more harm. I don't want to think about this one. I can't see any ending to the story that won't break my heart if that's true.

Comment: Well, perhaps it is the myth surrounding the Cthaeh because of all the harm that has been caused by people leaving the tree that it is all-knowing, but perhaps that is not the case.  Perhaps it has limits that we don't yet know about (without which, there can be no happy ending to the king chronicles).

Comment: That's why I think option 1 or 2 is the most likely.

Comment: Who says that it's tree is not *precisely* where it wants to be because there it can do the most damage?

Comment: I am convinced the Cthaeh cannot be both perfectly omniscient and perfectly malevolent. There must be a limit to one or the other, otherwise how did it get stuck in that tree? (Also, why do the tree's guardians not simply kill it?)

Answer (score 6):

The power of the Cthaeh is

> to see all the possible futures. This means that through the butterfly effect, he has the power to change the world dramatically. Since he cannot leave the tree, his only tool to effect change is the conversations he has with people. So for example, the Cthaeh could inflame Kvothe's opinions of Ambrose and it may later cause Kvothe to kill Ambrose, thus causing Ambrose's father to kill Kvothe, thus causing a civil war between the Maer and King of Vintas.

However, I personally believe that the Cthaeh is not as powerful as he is made out to by Bast.

> Sure, it can see all the possible futures. But that does not necessarily mean that it can make that future occur via its words. For example, if a person is dying of poison and Cthaeh talks to him, can the Cthaeh really accomplish anything?

As to what Kvothe does, it seems that he kills a King (in Imre) because of Denna, and that plunges the world in a devastating civil war.

Comment: It's defended for that very reason.  What damage can the tree do if  people leaving it are killed no questions asked?  I wonder why they don't try to destroy the tree once and for all.

Answer (score 3):

More spoilers.

> You can tell what Kvothe does from the title of the series, which is *The Kingkiller Chronicles*. He kills a king, which causes the political chaos that we see in the framing narrative. It's not yet clear which king he kills.

And.

> I'm sure we'll be getting more about the Cthaeh in the third book, but don't underestimate the power of being able to reveal any truth, and knowing exactly how things will work out if you do.

Comment: Damn, at some point in the second book I was certain I knew which king was meant. Now I can’t retrace my reasoning any more.

Comment: I would wager that the king he kills would be Ambrose, given that he keeps moving closer to the throne all the time.

Comment: Also remember that it has a fruit that can cure any wounds or heal any disease, which many of the Fae seem to desire. This might be worth keeping it alive.

Answer (score 1):

The Cthaeh is the loss of free will. Because of its ability to see all available futures and choose among them, anything you do afterwards will be because the Cthaeh either planned it or allowed it.

It does seem to me that the Cthaeh's power is incompatible with quantum uncertainty. There will be events over which it has no control e.g. quantum or geological; and thus its ability to control would diminish over time.

Answer (score 1):

On the nature of its power.

Let's go off what we observe and draw a set of conclusions, rather then a single overarching theme.

I perpose that The cthaeh gains some power after each level of interaction with what ever it comes in contact with. Listening to it, talking to it, asking it a question, asking it a favor, etc..

This happens explicitly and Felurian asks Kvothe about these "did you speak, did you ask of it, did it bite you (touch you)"

I suspect that the Cthaeh isn't all knowing, instead at each level of interaction it gains power over the subject. After Kvothe asks its a question it becomes very talkative and knows a lot about Kvothe's life. I believe it gained the power to know everything Kvothe does, but like a machine it sees everything all at once, it can piece things together Kvothe couldn't.

It flowers in couple well informed guesses (e.g that denna was hurt using a cane recently) to mask its true nature or maybe just to steer things in the direction it wants.

Comment: There's no evidence to suggest this being the Cthaeh's power. We have two reliable characters both explain what the Cthaeh is and how it works.Honestly, if it could only make decisions based on the knowledge of its victim, it's not all that dangerous - but if it was omniscient, then it becomes a much greater threat because now it knows exactly what to say to guide you towards the worst result possible - not just for yourself, but globally.

Comment: @mageXy 

Then why does Felurian make a big deal about "asking of it" vs "talking to it". The Cthaeh itself emphasis those two states. It prompts kvothe several times to ask it things.

We can ignore that, and call it omniscient, but that ignores the only true account we have of it. It knew things about Kvoths life, it gave no proof it knows everything. Flurean says it has the "gift of seeing". I surmise its a powerful seer, not omniscient. It's just got a blown up reputation because thats how stories work, thats theme of this entire series. It's called out explicitly in this case.

Comment: Felurian specifically states the the Cthaeh only speaks truth. A guess is not the truth, it merely an assumption (that can be completely wrong). So if it only speaks the truth, how could it tell Kvothe about Denna and the beatings if Kvothe himself didn't know for sure? And again, a creature that can "read" a person's mind/memories is not nearly as dangerous as one that can see every future. As Bast says, "an arrow only hits one person... Anyone influenced by the Cthaeh is like a plague ship sailing for a harbor." And Bast seem quite sure about his knowledge of the Cthaeh.

Comment: @MageXy your right of she says it only speaks the truth. So taken literally that would contradict that it lies directly. Though it certainly tells half-truths.

But regardless, the mind-reading is probably the lesser of the interesting parts of this. The larger part being the theory that gains more power the more you ask of it. Something like:

1. listen
2. talk
3. ask advice
4. ask for an object of power

Mostly, I'm saying it's not an all-seeing god. Again, it's probably a very powerful seer bound to the tree as a form of prison. It has rules and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, and this explains why the answers range from 'the cthaeh is the total worst' to 'potentially not that bad', is that the entire story makes use of the unreliable narrator writing effect.

In the same way that the books highlight just how a legend of a hero or villain can be over exaggerated with Qvoth's retelling compared to the patrons of the pub's retelling of his various exploits, its possible that the Cthaeh also experiences the same misinformed legend.

We can safely assume that the retelling of Qvoth's story by Qvoth himself is reliable, because although its fantastical it is also accepting of several basic truths behind the mystical elements. In Qvoth's retelling of the encounter with the Cthaeh, the Cthaeh admits to having to make assumptions about what Qvoth has been thinking of Denna: "youve thought of her too, im guessing".

There are several ways of explaining this, maybe Qvoth incorrectly remembered the events, maybe the Cthaeh carefully chose its words, maybe the Cthaeh cannot read events as accurately when they occur in Felurian's domain but taken at face value its possible to assume that the influence the creature has is not as strong as the rumours.

Answer (score -1):

The Cthaeth's control is as described above by Kushana. Because of quantum uncertainty it can only vastly increase the probabilities involved. For instance it cant change Kvothe causing him to kill some king but it can change him to the point where there is a 90% chance he will kill a king. Also the more that incredibly small parts of the  90% do not occur (which would occur over time) the less influence the Cthaeth has. Therefore it eventually loses the influence from 1 interference.

In other words there is a chance for a happy ending.

Answer (score -2):

I thought it was a solid creation, but not believable. The Cthaeh is a good example of PRockfuss' stylistic "weaknesses" (which don't need to bother you), which is being emphatic and emotional or rhetorical rather than proving. If he tells you that something is really, really bad, he can be insistent enough that the reader just goes with it. But the horribleness of the Cthaeh can't be that great for reasons of probability. Since it is bound to actual conditions, there is obviously a limit to what it can do and how bad it can be.

The thing tells you only the truth. So either it needs to coincidentally meet a person which is haunted by traumatic experiences (and unable to overcome them, so the Cthaeh might not even make a big difference), or knows somebody who currently undergoes a horrible treatment; or the author buys into an idea of truth that is less informative, useful, necessary or neutral than actively harmful, or can freely be given a harmful bent, and is ultimately impossible for any average individual to bear. Which is contrary to the necessity of (relevant) information, even bad one, in life, and therefore extremely strange (albeit convincing in a minor, melodramatic tradition).

The second reason why the Cthaeh is the most horrible thing in existence, which is not limited to the hearer's psyche, is that it tells you things which will come to pass as long as it gauges the hearer's reactions correctly (which it always does) and so makes the hearer part of the events. Now that is a really cool concept, but it doesn't work either. The likelihood that any hearer is or can be made an important actor in events, again relies on the hearer, their background, capabilities and interests, and the set of conditions in the world, and what difference a piece of information can actually make in it. The suggestion is that the Cthaeh of course chooses the worst possible outcome, but that doesn't make it any more likely that the consequences are momentous or so incredibly harmful.

And the two evils pretty much don't work together, as the first one (traumatise until you lose your personality...) has to fail a little in order for the second one to work, and if the first one can fail, it is admitted that the second one can (since the conditions are related), and in fact both failing contains a gigantic likelihood, making the Cthaeh practically an unscary "mean" fairytale spirit.

It might actually work within his world (which is why one can go with it), even always, but only in a fictional world. Even if it is all-knowing and evil, it is is still completely dependent on the conditions and factors, i.e. the persons and what they could/would actually do (and what difference it can play for the worst outcome).

Comment: Your answer could use some editing. I would suggest less verbage and more source quotes to back up your answer.

Comment: "Source quotes"? Show me others using source quotes. Have you even read the book?

Comment: I'm making an argument. The information is intrinsic common knowledge about the thing.

Comment: Interesting argument.  With everything that happens in this world (or the world of the Kingslayer Chronicles), the good and the bad kind of averages out, though we honestly can't say with any certainty what happens when the very worst possible thing happens.  It's a bit like a bad luck explosion centered around one person's timeline, with a small chance of creating a chain reaction.  It's difficult to say really.

Comment: The idea of people doing something because of being told something, and that action necessarily being profoundly negative, just seems like a total exaggeration to me, and completely fictional. There is in fact no proof or argument made that it would be very bad, it is just suggested by "worst possible" information, but that alone doesn't mean much. No matter how bad it is, it seems rather limited in its likelihood to be extremely bad, and worse than, say, a fairy killer squad. The likelihood would of course be higher and more complicated if anyone had free access.

Comment: Imagine a bad king getting informed of a way to win. That would be really bad. But even that doesn't mean that the better king has no chance to do anything about it. The information could be limited in its scope, and the rest would depend on other things (which no information influences). And the better king could still have been smart enough to make plans for his weaknesses to lessen the impact ("truth"?). The argument is similar to the butterfly effect, but not everything is necessarily connected in that way, or biased. But the Cthaeh seems to be build into the structure of the world, so OK.

Comment: @ Joe L. If your dickishness is suppposed to prove something (other than that), my argument is expressly concerned with more than this (the same as the book's rhetoric), i.e. the degree (and guaranteed bias) of the effect and relevance of the information, and special conditions which are hard to achieve for that (and in which the Cthae not always seems to make a difference). But what to expect of someone who claims Sauron losing the ring by bad luck is hardly different than being wrestled down at a high cost, or thinks the argument of the Cthae as "worst monster" is to be resolved by a quote.

Comment: @Mathias Suppose the Cthaeh tells you something that causes you to grab a gun and shoot the one guy that will be father to the person that will bring about a golden age on earth, if for no reason other than the fact that it turns out many years back he slept with your wife.  You could distance it further by the Cthaeh causing you to tell your friend that his wife is cheating on him and kill him that way.  It is said that [there are 6 degrees of separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) afterall.

Comment: While there's some fair points here, this sounds less like providing an answer to the question and sounds more like an attempt to debate, even before I look at comments.  Might be better places for it.  Also, try to spell the author's name right.

Comment: @ Neil: I don't disagree with that at all. Notice that this is part of the argument. It's reliant on very special conditions, limiting how bad it can be. And by the way, it's not an empirical theory of action. It is simply assumed that worst facts always cause worst action. I am pointing out that it doesn't work applied to reality. And that is because information only goes so far to influence anyone's actions. Do you think the world would be better with not getting bad news? So I say it is melodramatic, and I am merciful this way (in another environment, someone might laugh at it).

Comment: And remember how you said "absurd fear". I am using the exact same point, that it's emphatic but not proven, and am simply trying to point out that it's not so unversally terrible, to make every contact with it guaranteed disaster.

Comment: @ Radhil: "Also, try to spell the author's name right." Are you familiar with abbreviations or blends? Like the author "Pterry"? Do you know who that is? It's ultimately a matter of taste, and is no serious point (and I used it only once), so I guess that's another petty jab, out of forum mob mentality (by disageeing with their precious leaders, no matter who bad manners).

Comment: Well, yes, I know who Terry Pratchett is.  Most people use a name like that in affection, and it's a common usage; yours appears to be neither, so my assumption.  And... mob?  Where? Most of this looks like you chatting with Neil.

Comment: "Mob mentality" because of the gratuitousness of most of your remarks, because of the other community-related reason I mentioned, the same as automatic arrogance. And abbreviation of course because it's shorter, out of informality, and/or because it's relatively transparent, all of which are "common". (And I might write a more concise version of my original post, but so far I have felt distracted and disinterested as a result of it.)

Comment: Besides, since, mainly going by the first comment, one should assume the lowest capacity for understanding and standard rather than the highest, it is worth pointing out that the only relevant information in an annoying person is that annoying person itself. This is not even covered by the Cthaeh's scheme of "truth", and in any case would be completely deflating of its original purpose.